# Python class members type hinting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-typing

I am using `PyCharm` to develop some Python app. I am trying to use as cutting-edge python as possible, so I am making use of new python features. I have a problem with `type hinting`.

Let's all take a look at my `DataAnalyzer` class:

```
class DataAnalyzer:

    def __init__(self, train_data: pd.DataFrame, test_data: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        self.train_data = train_data
        self.test_data = test_data

    def analyze(self):
        pass
```

Now PyCharm spams me with yellow bulbs wanting me to add type annotations to `self.train_data` and `self.test_data`. If I click this message to do so, PyCharm adds two lines at the beginning of my class:

```
class DataAnalyzer:
    train_data: pd.DataFrame
    test_data: pd.DataFrame

    def __init__(self, train_data: pd.DataFrame, test_data: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        self.train_data = train_data
        self.test_data = test_data

    def analyze(self):
        pass
```

I guess now it looks nicer, but AFAIK by writing those variables like this I make them **static**.

I thought about annotating the types like this:

```
class DataAnalyzer:

    def __init__(self, train_data: pd.DataFrame, test_data: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        self.train_data: pd.DataFrame = train_data
        self.test_data: pd.DataFrame = test_data

    def analyze(self):
        pass
```

Which is definitely not clear, but I am not making my class members static, when I don't want to.

I know, that by having the types annotated in the method signature, doing this one more time when I just assign those, is an overkill, but I am asking for the general rule. Should I annotate those types like PyCharm suggests me to, or should I do this inline?

Comment: it's weird, which PyCharm version are you using? in my code it works fine with initial approach

Comment: By the way, it does not make the members static: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations

Comment: @AzatIbrakov it works, but PyCharm suggests me to change it

Comment: @UnholySheep so unless I annotate a variables as a `ClassVar` - it's not static, right?

Comment: Yes, `ClassVar` are (static) class variables, while otherwise it's an instance member. Though as described later in the PEP your last approach is also considered a valid convention (possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959876/type-hints-convention-for-instance-variables-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type Hints Convention for Instance Variables Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959876/type-hints-convention-for-instance-variables-python)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

PyCharm's suggest is right. In fact, I think the following code is better:

```py
class DataAnalyzer:
    train_data: pd.DataFrame
    test_data: pd.DataFrame

    def __init__(self, train_data, test_data):
        self.train_data = train_data
        self.test_data = test_data

    def analyze(self):
        pass
```

Explain:

- Annotate a member does not make it static.
- We should not annotate arguments in the `__init__` function again.
- `-> None` after `__init__` can be omitted. For `__init__` never return a value.

Comment: Your comment regarding `-> None` contradicts [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-meaning-of-annotations): "Note that the return type of `__init__` ought to be annotated with `-> None`. The reason for this is subtle. If `__init__` assumed a return annotation of `-> None`, would that mean that an argument-less, un-annotated `__init__` method should still be type-checked? Rather than leaving this ambiguous or introducing an exception to the exception, we simply say that `__init__` ought to have a return annotation; the default behavior is thus the same as for other methods."

Comment: Why should you not annotate the types of the init parameters? They are carrying the same name as the instance members, but they are in fact different variables.

Comment: @Sternerson, you are right. Another point to annotate `__init__` parameters is to get prompts from pycharm when you instantiate object (call its constructor).

Comment: Thanks for this. I definitely think it's easier to read. The only thing is that the variable appears in two places: once at the class definition, once in `__init__` so this makes it slightly morre difficult to change things.

Comment: I don't consider this method, artificial class attributes with same name as instance attributes,  as correct. In fact, you setup both class and instance attributes with same name and I consider it misleading and potentially error prone. Class attributes are used for different purposes.

Comment: @karel-marik FYI the type hints do not create class attributes in this example. That only happens if a value is assigned. It's explained in https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations "the value-less notation `a: int` allows one to annotate instance variables that should be initialized in `__init__`" Also I tested some sample code similar to this and confirmed that it does not create a class attribute.

Answer (score 13):

Both options are valid - check out [pep 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations)

> Type annotations can also be used to annotate class and instance variables in class bodies and methods. In particular, the value-less notation `a: int` allows one to annotate instance variables that should be initialized in `__init__` or `__new__`.

The [MyPy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/class_basics.html#instance-and-class-attributes) is also a good resource for type hinting