# How to generate the UML diagram from the python code

Tags: python, uml, class-diagram, pyreverse

I have this code [repo](https://github.com/ninjakx/Low-Level-Design/tree/main/LLD(Python)/ShoppingCart)

I created manual UML which look like this:
[image]

I am trying to auto generate the UML via [pyreverse](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyreverse.html):

`pyreverse -o png -p ShoppingCart ./mainService.py`

> Format png is not supported natively. Pyreverse will try to generate
> it using Graphviz...

Unfortunately, it gives me blank diagram. What can I do to get the project's classes in the diagram?

This is the file structure:

```
.
├── Entity
│   ├── Apple.py
│   ├── Buy1Get1FreeApple.py
│   ├── Buy3OnPriceOf2Orange.py
│   ├── Offer.py
│   ├── Orange.py
│   ├── Product.py
│   └── ShoppingCart.py
├── Enum
│   └── ProductType.py
└── mainService.py
```

Comment: Did you install `graphviz` or `dot`, as the documentation tells you?

Comment: Yes I did install graphviz because I was getting some error at that time related to this module and also this moduel was required. using `brew install graphviz`

Comment: `dot -V` also works --> 
`dot - graphviz version 9.0.0 (20230911.1827)`

Comment: The error message is absolutely normal.  It just tells that it's not an internal format of pyreverse.  The problem is that either the command line is not complete, considering that you did not package your modules properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In short

Assuming the installation of pyreverse and graphviz is correct,  all you need to do is to package your project adding some emplty __init__py files in each folder.  Alternatively, you'd hjhave to add all the modules manually in the command line.

## More details - step by step

### About the error message

Assuming everything is installed correctly,  your command line should give you the warning message, which is absolutely normal:

> Format png is not supported natively. Pyreverse will try to generate
> it using Graphviz...

### What's wrong?

The diagram will stay empty because you tell pyreverse to analyse a single file and there is no class defined in that file.  If you'd add manually the different modules to be analysed:

```
pyreverse -o png -p ShoppingCart mainService.py Entity\Apple.py Enum\ProductType.py Entity\Orange.py Entity\ShoppingCart.py
```

you would then very well obtain a rudimentary diagram:

[image: four classes side by side]

If you would add the options `-AS` upfront you'd get all ancestors in the project and all associated classes recursively:

[image]

### How to package your project?

This is cumbersome.  Fortunately, there's little missing to package your project.  For a full reference, you may look [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/).  But in short, it is sufficient to add an empty `__init__.py` file in your project folder, and each subfolder where you store the modules:

```
.
├── Entity
│   ├── __init__.py                   <<===== add this empty file
│   ├── Apple.py
│   ├── Buy1Get1FreeApple.py
│   ├── Buy3OnPriceOf2Orange.py
│   ├── Offer.py
│   ├── Orange.py
│   ├── Product.py
│   └── ShoppingCart.py
├── Enum
│   ├── __init__.py                   <<===== add this empty file
│   └── ProductType.py
├── __init__.py                       <<===== add this empty file
└── mainService.py
```

You will then be able to run the simpler command line:

```
pyreverse -AS -o png -p ShoppingCart .
```

and obtain this magnificient diagram:

[image]

The packaging helps python and pyreverse to understand that these are not files to be analysed in isolation,  but in the context of a package made of subpackages, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the link and providing the detailed answer. it shows only some variable under the eligibleProduct. Not the descriptive one. Is it because method/data memebrs are protected and private?

Comment: @Pygirl indeed, it seems that renaming it without double underscore for example offerType show it on the diagram.  On the other hand,  __offerOnProduct is shown  on the diagram as "role" (syntactically it should be at the end on the side of the target class, but it's there.  For the other variables,  you also need to know that there are some limitations on what pyreverse can do,  see for example this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76147751/3723423 (corrected) or https://stackoverflow.com/q/72388388/3723423 (answer confirmed in the comments by one of pyreverse co-authors)