# Type hinting a list with coupled inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, pycharm, type-hinting

I'm using Python 3.7.6 with PyCharm. I want my code to work as a nice internal API with code completion appearing for objects so I want to use typing.

I'm trying to find a good pattern for when:

- There are two groups of classes with each group having it's own inheritance tree
- and objects from one group are composed of lists of objects from other group

(example below)

I've found a way below but it feels like a hack. What's the right (or better) way to do this?

```
from typing import List, Type

class Leg:
    def step(self):
        print("step")

class DuckLeg(Leg):
    def paddle(self):
        print("splosh")

class Biped:
    def __init__(self, leg_type: Type[Leg]):
        self.legs: List[leg_type] = [leg_type(), leg_type()]

    def walk(self):
        for leg in self.legs:
            leg.step()

class Duck(Biped):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(leg_type=DuckLeg)
        self.legs: List[DuckLeg] = self.legs  # A hack?

my_duck = Duck()
my_duck.walk()              # code-completion appears for .walk()
my_duck.legs[0].paddle()    # code-completion appears for .paddle()
```

Edit 1: This question is not about where to put the type annotations but how to ensure code-completion works in this context. If the following line is commented-out...

```
self.legs: List[DuckLeg] = self.legs
```

...the code will still run because of duck-typing but code-completion will not appear for .paddle() and when manually entered PyCharm code inspection will report: Unresolved attribute reference 'paddle' for class 'Leg'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type Hints Convention for Instance Variables Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959876/type-hints-convention-for-instance-variables-python)

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks for commenting. It was an interesting read but doesn't answer my question unfortunately. It's not about where in the class definition to put type annotations (see edit above).

Comment: But what if you comment out that line, and add the line `legs: List[DuckLeg]` under `class Duck(Biped)` instead? Would that not have the same effect, while not being a hack?

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks for coming back. I agree that would be less of a hack. Sadly it doesn't give me the nice internal API I'm looking for without the assignment (for reasons I don't understand). So still no code completion and still the code inspection error doing it the way you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this actually solves your problem but I think it's cleaner than what you propose:

```py
from typing import List, Type

class Leg:
    def step(self):
        print("step")

class DuckLeg(Leg):
    def paddle(self):
        print("splosh")

class Biped:
    LegType = Leg
    def __init__(self):
        # self.LegType always gives the correct leg type for the instance
        self.legs: List[self.LegType] = [self.LegType(), self.LegType()]

    def walk(self):
        for leg in self.legs:
            leg.step()

class Duck(Biped):
    LegType = DuckLeg
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jdehesa. I agree it's more readable and it runs. Two problems unfortunately: List[self.LegType] in the Biped.__init__ method is now raising a red code-inspection error "invalid self" for self.LegType. I tried changing this to Biped.LegType but that doesn't help as Biped.LegType is Leg, even in __init__. An unchanged class variable I'm guessing. Back to the original question, code-inspection for .paddle() doesn't appear and when entered manually code-inspection flags it as a warning. Thanks though. I learned something :)